# Android - why do two TextView elements line up side by side instead of one below the next?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solution_title"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label1"
    />  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solution_description"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label2"
    />  

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am combining two TextView elements with a ListView. For some reason, the TextView items render next to each other instead of one below the other.  Why does that happen? And how do I make them line up one below the other?

Thanks!

Comment: try adding this android:orientation="vertical" in your LinearLayout

Comment: Did your adapter problem get solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the LinearLayout you need to specify the orientation as follow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `LinearLayout` has a horizontal orientation by default.
Specify `android:orientation="vertical"` for it.

Answer (score 1):

See [LinearLayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)

But you want: `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the attribute:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello See Vertical orientation

You may consider to have two linear layouts and have the vertical orientation within another linear layout which is horizontal if that helps.